# Codeigniter cannot load helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I have checked all config files, made sure the helpers are in both system/helpers and application/helpers as well as one or the other. I have tried autoloading helpers, loading the helper in my controller and from the view and no matter what I get an error.

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php

It is treating it as if I am trying to load a blank helper such as `$this->load->helper('');` but I am using `$this->load->helper('url');`

This is my controller to load my home page

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
}
```

system/helpers/url_helper.php and application/helpers/url_helper.php both currently exist and have not been edited at all.

If needed I can include my autoload.php but the helper Auto-load Helper Files is currently `$autoload['helper'] = array();`

Comment: Helper files doesn't exist in `APPPATH.'helpers/'` directory by default. Just noticing that you say it's not edited. It is already set there by someone. Try to backup that file, remove it ant try again to see what will happen.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean to remove the helper files from the directory and then place them back in?

Comment: Remove custom helper file from application directory and try to load just default one from system directory.

Comment: I am not trying to load any custom helpers, only trying to load the default url helper

Comment: You can check in github repo. There is no helper files in `application/helpers` by default.

Comment: I did try to move the default helpers to application/helpers to see if it would work, but besides attempting that I am only working with default helpers in the system/helpers directory

Comment: You don't need to touch system files, like ever. Everything you need to write or extend should be in application directory. Never touch/move/modify system directory files.

Comment: So far I have not actually "changed" anything in system, I only copied the helper files and pasted them into application/helpers and when that did not work I removed them from application/helpers. I still do not understand why I am getting this error though.

Comment: Is that existing app? If it is new one, try to install from scratch.

Comment: I tried reinstalling from scratch and get the same error

Comment: The only thing I can think of that I have done differently from standard is I put my images, css, and js into an assets directory

Comment: Instead in constructor, try autoload in `application/config/autoload.php` file. For this you have to move loading line in constructor - you shouldn't load same helper twice. Any difference then?

Comment: There was no difference

Answer (score 0):

If you need to over ride the url helper

rename the file

```
application/helpers/MY_URL_helper.php
```

OR

```
application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work. Any way I try to load the helpers I get Unable to load the requested file: helpers/_helper.php even after reinstalling CI

Comment: @achill113 have your made sure your filename is Pages.php not pages.php

Comment: All of my controller files have the first letter capitalized

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole path inside the url, like this , (wamp)

```
$this->load->helper('www/projectfoldername/applications/libraries/helpers/helperfile');
```

Comment: This makes ABSOLUTELY no sense to me, but when I put $this->load->helper("url///"); it worked. For each slash one of the characters showed up.